# Using discriminating unions in react props with a default

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript, discriminated-union, typescript-types

I have a react component that has 3 variants. I have my props typed like this:

```
enum VariantType {
  VARIANT_1 = "variant_1",
  VARIANT_2 = "variant_2",
  VARIANT_3 = "variant_3",
}

type BaseProps = {
  a: string;
}

type Variant1Props = BaseProps & {
  variant: VariantType.VARIANT_1;
  b: never;
}

type Variant2Props = BaseProps & {
  variant: VariantType.VARIANT_2;
  b: number;
}

type Variant3Props = BaseProps & {
  variant: VariantType.VARIANT_3;
  b: boolean;
}

export const FancyComponent: FunctionComponent<Variant1Props | Variant2Props | Variant3Props> = (props) => {
  const someNumber = props.variant === VariantType.VARIANT_2 ? props.b : 123; 
   ...
}
```

In the assignment of someNumber TS knows that `b` is defined because I checked the variant. When using the component TS complains when `b` is present when it's `VARIANT_1` and it complains when `b` is not present/not a number when it's `VARIANT_2` (same for `VARIANT_3`).

What I'm looking for now is a way to make the `variant` option optional when using the component and it should default to `VARIANT_1` and you could set it to `VARIANT_2` or `VARIANT_3` without loosing any of the type-safety I have now.

I tried stuff with generics and so on but couldn't get it to work.

I'm using Typescript 4.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the `variant` property in `Variant1Props` optional, and it all works:

```
enum VariantType {
  VARIANT_1 = "variant_1",
  VARIANT_2 = "variant_2",
  VARIANT_3 = "variant_3",
}

type BaseProps = {
  a: string;
}

type Variant1Props = BaseProps & {
  variant?: VariantType.VARIANT_1;
  b: never;
}

type Variant2Props = BaseProps & {
  variant: VariantType.VARIANT_2;
  b: number;
}

type Variant3Props = BaseProps & {
  variant: VariantType.VARIANT_3;
  b: boolean;
}

// to check that props.b actually has type never
declare function expectTheUnexpected(wtf: never): void;

export const FancyComponent = (props: Variant1Props | Variant2Props | Variant3Props) => {
  const someNumber = props.variant === VariantType.VARIANT_2 ? props.b : 123;
  if (!props.variant) expectTheUnexpected(props.b);
  // ...
}
```

And [in the Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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).

But realistically, you don’t want `b: never`—that is telling TS to expect (and require) an actual property `b`, but that the value of that property is `never`. That means that `{ a: 'foo' }` is not a valid `Variant1Props`, so `<FancyComponent a="foo" />` won’t work. Instead, a valid `Variant1Props` needs to be something like `{ a: 'foo', b: someVariableWithTypeNever }`,¹ which is a mess. Really, `never` is rarely a type you actually expect to work with, it’s supposed to indicate that something went wrong and we’re now in a situation that the type system says can’t happen.

What you actually want for the definition of `Variant1Props` is

```
type Variant1Props = BaseProps & {
  variant?: VariantType.VARIANT_1;
  b?: undefined;
}
```

Now `b` may or may not actually be present, but if you include it, it’s gotta be just `undefined` (which means it may as well not be present). So `{ a: 'foo' }` works, but `{ a: 'foo', b: 42 }` doesn’t—`42` isn’t `undefined`. To be allowed to put `b: 42`, we need to put in `variant: VariantType.VARIANT_2`.

1. <sub>I.e. the component is generated with `<FancyComponent a="foo" b={someVariableWithTypeNever} />`—I’m going to stop bringing React into this, it doesn’t affect the question at all.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

Once you destructure your `props` it's too late to discriminate them together because they're no longer associated to each other. Instead, you need to discriminate the object itself, then destructure. Here are a few ways you can do that:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=31&ssc=1&pln=68&pc=2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwFBzgEwKYDMCGBXAG3hwGc4AlDHAYxgBoU4YBPMDCq2gUQIxAwB29JAF84WKBBBwA5FE4wZAbiRJBeaQDUcUYDiEAVVu2SpNAQXIBJcwDkDAfQCMcALxwARADcdeoc48GM0sbewcAJjdPH119GAjAxgtrO0cAZijvXziHNMSRVRY2OAAhUgwABUkwMndTOBwALjgSGF0BAHMVERUkIvZtWKEnKogaqLKSSuqyADJERhi-GGbB5aM2ADpk0McnFVQAI2aBDC8MKG7e-rg1uPDR8fdJ6bG5hdQluNXsw2NtkKpCIHODHOACDSHC5XQrGW6-GBpR61UrlZFweb1L5CH5DGAbDAAlJhNIgsGHCAQXj6GF9OHmAgEO5CFHMmAjGZwAA+8LxD05PLZSJmvQA9KK4FwAB44cC8OBONRSyCwODUCACVpwABi+mozAAwlJIKdhlEABRgGbNBlMhEkACUzUoNBgPD4gngrgAfB81RqtSQpBhbJCLlErW9Ntiva53GyCUTdhE4AB+OCRmqbQ5wZpOcKkuDi8FhqCMeQwPBQARwAA8aGAXm9tdFDab3VUxelsrA8vCzQAqiRgJ1-QIGzBgBqcAQlSr4OrNfBdQJ9UbwBrPZF3JbrXBbWzHc6FO7+EI3L76sAsHBd1GY2447z1v8dkDwg6-ahF1r6qhUDgdBFhKrTtB0jD-qCQHFhCIBQmWkGfAi0ESgmr6AmE4QQXAYjuJmJAggUqAVlWNb1o2zathRHadhK3ZyuwaTNNKbSuiOHRjhOU4CDOcAjnAADEkQwBAGbyA21A4DAGCNEgxYABYwDANSNOKADuGmbP0JDULoYAwAQ+gdJs0AdK2EDUCQoryfoaAUhAADWorhKKPFQJIansZsikgAQAl4MOnQALT9EFVoYBJUkYCQqhYHgq6ThqfEkGykR3ip+6MoeTpiW8yXPvc6L1CR1a5VmD5xvGCKJm+mE0RgyrQAuAbLnqhrGpuQgZDu+E2ll9o5S63C8GeXqXow163sAKUIuE6WOp+f5jr+2EAShLRtOxq1QcBJZwRc20xutaFbLVjhYZBuFlQRjBEXAJVkW2lFPd0QA)

```ts
type AllVariants = Variant1Props | Variant2Props | Variant3Props;

// Example 1
export const FancyComponent1 = (props: AllVariants): ReactElement => {
  const someNumber = props.variant === VariantType.VARIANT_2 ? props.b : 123; // number
  return <div></div>;
}

// Example 2: Using conditional
export const FancyComponent2 = (props: AllVariants): ReactElement => {
  if (props.variant === VariantType.VARIANT_2) {
    const {
      a, // string
      b, // number
      variant, // VariantType.VARIANT_2
    } = props;
  }
  return <div></div>;
}


// Example 3: Extracting conditional in #2 to predicate:
// https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates

function isVariant2 (props: AllVariants): props is Variant2Props {
  return props.variant === VariantType.VARIANT_2;
}

export const FancyComponent3 = (props: AllVariants): ReactElement => {
  if (isVariant2(props)) {
    const {
      a, // string
      b, // number
      variant, // VariantType.VARIANT_2
    } = props;
  }
  return <div></div>;
}
```

Comment: @PieterVanderHaegen By the way, there are a few syntax errors in your code which will prevent compilation. If they were just typos in the question: no big deal. But if you need help with that, they're fixed in the playground link in the answer.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question correctly. While you're right there where some syntax errors and the destructuring did indeed influence the types (updated both things in the question), that was not the gist of my question. The gist of my question is to find a way that gives the same typesafety with a default variant.